# What AI theory uses "win" counts to determine strategy?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am new to AI, and was wondering what (if any) AI theory best describes the following scenario:

I have an agent that can be programmed to execute one of three states in a competitive scenario. I program the agent to execute each state five times. A win count is maintained while testing each state. Results would look something like this:

```
State      Wins
1          3
2          1
3          3
```

After all testing is complete, the state(s) with the highest (and joint highest) win count are determined from the results set. In the above example, states 1 and 3 are determined as being the most effective states.

Comment: First of all, I think this kind of question is better suited for http://ai.stackexchange.com/ because it isn't really about a specific programming problem. That being said, I think you best start looking into *learning rules in game theory* and *reinforcement learning*. I think you'll find many algorithms that do exactly this if you research those terms. The part where you "execute each state five times" is called an *exploration mechanism/strategy*.

Comment: Thanks for the link and info.

Comment: Also, for machine learning related questions you can go to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ;)